# Is it possible to type-check only imported libraries (Typescript, VSCode)?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

**Basic question:** Is it possible to type-check only `import`s?

I *do* want to know

- `TS: property 'id' does not exist on type 'Stripe.customer'` (for example)
- but *not* on my own objects, like `property 'prop1' does not exist on type '{}'`

**Background**

- I'm working on a Javascript project, and I'd like to use Typescript for added intellisense with imported libraries, while otherwise writing in JS, so I've changed my `.js` file to `.ts` during development. († see bottom)
- In the Javascript project, lots of objects are initialized as `let x = {}` and then properties are later added as `x.prop1 = value1`.
- TSLint then warns me, `property 'prop1' does not exist on type 'x'`.

I would like to get this warning only on imports.

- For instance, if I `import * as stripe from 'stripe'`, then it's helpful to get the warning `property 'id' doest not exist on type 'customer'`.
- Following this thread, [property does not exists on type '{}'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34274487/property-does-not-exists-on-type) , I can achieve this manually on a per-object basis by converting `x.prop1` to `x['prop1']`.
- I've also experimented with inline comments to disable various TSLint rules, but the warnings are coming from the Typescript language features in VSCode, not TSLint.

**However, to restate the question more precisely:**
Is there directive or config option that would allow me to add properties to objects defined in my *own* code without warning, while still warning/type-checking imported libraries?

† If there's a alternative, less janky way to get intellisense on imported libraries in Javascript, I'm all ears!

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, I was able to achieve this by

1. keeping my file extension `.js` instead of `.ts` (which I was only using becuse I thought it was necessary to enable type checking)
2. adding a `tsconfig.json` file to my project, with the following settings to enable type checking JS:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "strict": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "outDir": "lib",
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
}
```

The result was that I could write `x.myProp` without warning, but `importedLibrary.propThatDoesNotExist` would throw a Typescript error.

And because `compileOnSave` is `false`, the compiler didn't actually take any actions, it just issues warnings -- effectively allowing *some* added TS features in a JS file, which is quite useful.

I believe this works *because* it's a Javascript file, and thus the TS compiler expects JS-style coding, but I'm not 100% sure.

Finally, a useful reference for the compiler options above: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html